# What does Sean mean with this sentence?

Tags: dialogue, good-will-hunting

In the movie [*Good Will Hunting* (1997)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119217/) in the scene where Will starts crying and they hug each other, what does Sean mean by telling Will "Fuck them OK"? Who is referring to? Is he referring in general to the people who abuse others? Or is he referring to his own father and Will's foster father in common? Or is he saying it without specially targeting anyone just to relieve Will?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took it as "Fuck everyone who puts you down. You're valuable. Everyone who doesn't think so isn't important."  So to me it sounded like a general statement.

I think the only one who could really answer this questions would have been Robin Williams. Actors come up with their own, personal interpretations of the lines they say. Without talking to them, it's impossible to know for sure (unless the line is really straightforward, which this one is not).